# Remove string from all cells where some elements are None

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this

```
Index | Column1      | Column2      | Column3      | Column 4     | Column 5    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0     | A1 (aliasA1) | A2 (aliasA2) | A3 (aliasA3) | None         | None        |
1     | B1 (aliasB1) | None         | None         | None         | None        |
2     | C1 (aliasC1) | C2 (aliasC2) | C3 (aliasC3) | C4 (aliasC4) | C5 (aliasC5)|
n     | Z1 (aliasZ1) | Z2 (aliasZ2) | None         | None         | None        |
```

I want to remove all the parenthesis and make it look like:

```
Index | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column 4 | Column 5 |
-----------------------------------------------------------
0     | A1      | A2      | A3      | None     | None     |
1     | B1      | None    | None    | None     | None     |
2     | C1      | C2      | C3      | C4       | C5       |
n     | Z1      | Z2      | None    | None     | None     |
```

I tried

```
df = df.replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r"\(.*\)",value=r'')
```

But I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: You don't need the second `r` for `value=r''` by the way. It's only needed for regular expressions when your string contains backslashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `inplace = True` means you already made change to the data frame and it will return None.
You can choose 1 solution below:

1. Remove the param `inplace=True`.

or

2. `df.replace(regex=True, inplace=True, to_replace=r"\(.*\)",value=r'')`

Comment: This looks more like a comment, not an answer.